# Hammer.js - Swipe in an off canvas element?

Tags: jquery, touch, swipe, hammer.js

I'm using the plugin [offCanvasMenu](http://cloudfour.github.io/offCanvasMenu/) to basically do what the plugin says.. hide and show an off canvas menu which works fine as a click event but I'm trying to integrate hammer.js so the menu will hide/show on a right swipe

So I've got this:

```
(function() {
    jQuery(function() {
        var $, configureMenus, menu, menuTrigger;

        $ = jQuery;
        menuTrigger = $('#menu-trigger');
        menu = $.offCanvasMenu({
            direction: 'right',
            coverage: '85%'
        });
        (configureMenus = function(display) {
            switch (display) {
                case 'block':
                menu.on();
                break;
                case 'none':
                menu.off();
                break;
                default:
                return;
            }
        })(menuTrigger.css('display'));
        menuTrigger.csswatch({
            props: 'display'
        }).on('css-change', function(event, change) {
            return configureMenus(change.display);
        });
    });
}).call(this);
```

I thought pasting the above into the following would have worked?

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() { 
    var element = document.getElementById('body');
    var hammertime = Hammer(element).on("swipe", function(event) {
        //here
    })
}, false);
```

But I haven't been able to call it in correctly, just wondering if anyone knows how to do this?

If it helps the basic markup is something like

```
<body id="body">
    <div id="menu-trigger" class="panel-arrow right"><a href="#menu">click me</a></div>

    <div id="menu" class="right-panel panel">
        <p>off canvas menu</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should go the other way around. Add the swipe event listener into the first block of code. And where your second block says //here, you should do something like menu.toggle().

Comment: Is it working? We designed it to allow for additions like this. But we never actually tried it.

Comment: Yeah its working great thanks. Only issue is that on the iphone for me the panel seems to awkwardly flash in rather than slide (when using swipe or the trigger button)

Comment: Are you including modernizr so that it will use CSS animation? Is there somewhere I could look at the page?